# Send mail from Mac numbers via AppleScript

Tags: automation, numbers, applescript

I have a numbers document where I have two tables inside. First one is like a simple form where I input data and select value from dropdown (name of the person and his e-mail + values used in the message). The second table is a place where message is generated.

```
I.e. in the first table I have:
subject: textfield
value1: dropdown
value2: dropdown
person: John Doe <john@doe.com>

Second table generates a mail message from table1 values:
Subject of mail: $subject
Hi, this is a request for $subject with properties $value1 , $value2. Responsible for your request is $person.
```

Right now, I copy/paste a message into the mail and put subject/person by hands. 
Can somebody please help with an applescript which I will call i.e. from the Script menu bar for numbers and it will create a message/+addressee&subject from the numbers values?

Maybe it is even possible to pull a specific stationery for the composed mail?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Number, but I assume you can extract values of Numbers cells into Applescript variables. then to create a mail :

```
set mySubject to "subject value from Numbers"
set myContent to "text content" -- in can be a concat of text and variables
set mySignature to "name of signature created in Mail"
set myContact to "joh,@doe.com"

tell application "Mail"
activate
set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {visible:true, subject:mySubject, content:myContent}
set message signature of newMessage to signature Ma_Signature -- not mandatory
tell newMessage
    make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:"", address:myContact}
end tell
end tell
```

you can add, or not, a send instruction just after, if you do not need to check your mail before sending.